# Time Series Forecasting Python | Constant Increasing Predictions

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, arima, facebook-prophet

This might seem like a stupid question, but i have been trying out Time Series Forecasting Techniques, and somehow both the techniques(Prophet & Auto-Arima) that i tried, seemed to give predictions in an increasing order?

What could be the possible reasons for getting constantly increasing predictions? I think it might be due to seasonality factor, but i am not really sure.

I can share the code if required.

The code is as follows:

```
data_v2 = pd.read_csv('data_v1.csv')
data_v2.shape
data_v2.head()
data_v2.dtypes

data_v2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_v2.Date,format='%m/%d/%Y')
data_v2.index = data_v2['Date']

#preparing data
data_v2.rename(columns={'Invoice Amount': 'y', 'Date': 'ds'}, inplace=True)
data_v2.head()
#train and validation
train = data_v2[:16]
train.shape
valid = data_v2[16:]
valid.shape

#fit the model
model = Prophet()
model.fit(train)

#predictions
close_prices = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=len(valid))
forecast = model.predict(close_prices)
forecast.head()
#rmse
forecast_valid = forecast['yhat'][16:]
rms=np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power((np.array(valid['y'])-np.array(forecast_valid)),2)))
print(rms)

valid['Predictions'] = 0
valid['Predictions'] = forecast_valid.values

plt.plot(train['y'])
plt.plot(valid[['y', 'Predictions']])


# Plot the forecast
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
f.set_figheight(5)
f.set_figwidth(15)
fig = model.plot(forecast, ax=ax)
plt.show()

fig = model.plot_components(forecast)
```

The following are the predictions:

```
0     30505.608982
1     31618.779403
2     32731.949825
3     33737.394077
4     34850.564499
5     35927.826201
6     37040.996625
7     38118.258327
8     39231.428751
9     40344.599176
10    41421.860877
11    42535.031302
12    43612.293004
13    44725.463429
14    45838.633854
15    46844.078108
16    46879.986832
17    46915.895555
18    46951.804279
19    46987.713002
20    47023.621725
21    47059.530449
22    47095.439172
23    47131.347896
```

Following are the actual values:

```
2016-12-01    63662.5
2017-01-01    35167.5
2017-02-01    24810.0
2017-03-01    25352.5
2017-04-01    19355.0
2017-05-01    21860.0
2017-06-01    21420.0
2017-07-01    30260.0
2017-08-01    26810.0
2017-09-01    29510.0
2017-10-01    84722.5
2017-11-01    71706.5
2017-12-01    44935.0
2018-01-01    43835.0
2018-02-01    35405.0
2018-03-01    40307.5
2018-04-01     26665.0
2018-05-01     27395.0
2018-06-01     89142.5
2018-07-01    100497.5
2018-08-01     41722.5
2018-09-01     30760.0
2018-10-01    183562.5
2018-11-01     90650.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sharing the code would help, but one sure thing is that if your predictions are always increasing with time, you most probably have a big positive trend in your time series and little to no seasonality.

Comment: Hi, i have edited the question. Hope it helps now!